# Electron getUserMedia deviceId not working

Tags: javascript, html, audio, electron, microphone

i got a problem with the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() function. I want to use a spcified device, so i passed in the deviceId to getUserMedia, but it's not working. No matter which deviceId i use, it's using the default micrphone all the time.

Here is my current code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Spectral Analyzer</title>
    <script>
      if (typeof module === "object") {
        window.module = module;
        module = undefined;
      }
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      if (window.module) module = window.module;
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 100vh;
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      #content {
        display: flex;
        flex: 9;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
      }

      .interact {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .selectArea {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .button {
        margin: 0 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="interact">
        <div class="selectArea">
          <button class="button" id="updateSelect">Update</button>
          <select id="select">
            <option value="default">No Devices</option>
          </select>
          <button class="button" id="start">Start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**renderer.js**

```
let foundDevices = [];
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let anim;

const start = async () => {
  canvas.width = $("#content").width();
  canvas.height = $("#content").height();

  // Stop animation if already running
  if (anim) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
  }

  // Search for available devices and push it into found devices array
  await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
    devices.forEach((device) => {
      foundDevices.push(device);
    });
  });
};

// Handling the incoming stream and analyse it in an array
const handleStream = (stream) => {
  console.log("stream: ", stream);
  let context = new AudioContext();
  let audioSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  let analyser = context.createAnalyser();

  audioSource.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);

  analyser.fftSize = 128;

  const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

  const barWidth = canvas.width / bufferLength;

  // Visualize the stream
  const renderFrame = () => {
    let filledWidth = 0;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
      let barHeight = dataArray[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
      ctx.fillRect(filledWidth, canvas.height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
      filledWidth += barWidth;
    }

    anim = requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
  };
  renderFrame();
};

const updateSelect = () => {
  $("#select").find("option").remove();
  $.each(foundDevices, (i, item) => {
    $("#select").append(
      $("<option>", {
        value: i,
        text: item.label,
      })
    );
  });
};

$(document).ready(() => {
  start();

  $("#updateSelect").click(() => {
    updateSelect();
  });

  $("#start").click(() => {
    const selectedDevice = $("#select").val();
    const constraints = {
      audio: {
        deviceId: { exact: foundDevices[selectedDevice].deviceId },
      },
      video: false,
    };
    console.log(constraints);
    try {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
        handleStream(stream);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

This problem exists in Electron and also in Chrome with an Apache2 server. In my example i need the audiooutput, but i can't choose it. The only error i get is this:

```
OverconstrainedError {name: 'OverconstrainedError', message: '', constraint: 'deviceId'}
constraint: "deviceId"
message: ""
name: "OverconstrainedError"
```

Best Regards
DreamGamer